# React TypeError: this.props.handleSubmit is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, typeerror

I've built a wrapped class component that is meant to submit data using an API request with axios. However, when I press the submit button I get the error `TypeError: this.props.handleSubmit is not a function`.

I've built similar components and they worked, but for some reason I'm getting this TypeError. Am I missing something?

#### Component

```js
class AddPlayer extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            name: "",
        };

        this.handleName = this.handleName.bind(this);
    };

    // Name Input
    handleName = e => {
        this.setState({
            name: e.currentTarget.value
        });
    };

    // handle form submit
    handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.handleClick({ ...this.state });

        this.setState({
            name: "",
        });

    };

    render() {
        const { name } = this.state;

        return (
            <form
                onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <h2>Input Player</h2>
                <div>
                    <div >
                        <label htmlFor="player name">
                            Enter new Player Name:
                        </label>

                        <input
                            type="text"
                            id="player name"
                            name="player name"
                            value={name}
                            onChange={this.handleName}
                            maxLength="25"
                            minLength="2"
                            required
                            ref={function (input) {
                                if (input != null) {
                                    input.focus();
                                }
                            }}
                        />
                    </div>

                    <button disabled={name.length <= 2} type="submit">Add Player</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        )
    };
};
```

#### index.js for the component

```js
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import AddPlayer from './AddPlayer';
import { postPlayer } from '../../data/actions/api';

// Dispatch 
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        handleClick: (data) => dispatch(postPlayer(data)),
    };
};

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(AddPlayer)
```

Comment: Try changing `connect(mapDispatchToProps)` to `connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)`

Comment: same error :/ I'm not sure why. Although I know what you're saying is definitely correct since mapDispatchToProps is the second argument not the first

Comment: I'm not, but I guess I could change the naming. Changed it now to "handleClick" to avoid future confusion

Answer (score 1):

The react-redux `connect` function takes `mapStateToProps` as the first argument and `mapDispatchToProps` as the second argument. If you don't have a `mapStateToProps`, you can just provide `null` as the first argument.

```js
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(AddPlayer)
```

**Edit:** For recordkeeping, the other issue was importing the unconnected component instead of the connected component when using it elsewhere.

Comment: Are you definitely using the connected component and not the unconnected component when you're importing it and using it elsewhere?

Comment: THAT WAS IT *facepalm* These react auto import things are starting to do my head in. I may start removing them. It was importing the .js instead of the directory

Comment: I've hit that countless times. I have adopted my own convention of naming the unconnected components like `UnconnectedAddPlayer` and then doing a named export of the connected component `export const AddPlayer = connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(UnconnectedAddPlayer)`.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't sure whether you could name the unconnected component something different. I'm a pretty new programmer and React is really challenging

Comment: Yeah! Another option is just not exporting the unconnected component at all and doing the redux connection/export in the same file

Comment: I find that so much easier! I did that in another component. this is part of a coding project I have to hand in, so I thought I'd make components in as many ways as possible, to show I was somewhat versed with a wide variety of them, it was time to use a wrapped class component

Answer (score 0):

please instead of  onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} do onSubmit={()=>this.handleSubmit()} and also same with onChange={this.handleName} do onChange={()=>this.handleName()}